# No overload for method Open takes 15 arguments (CS1501)

Tags: ranorex

I am using 2013 Excel and am testing a web application where i need to analyze a excel file using code so i found a code which i have modified according to ranorex namings. but am new to ranorex so getting few errors. this is the error am facing even after adding the reference.
 No overload for method 'Open' takes 15 arguments (CS1501)

Please help me out
/

```
*
 * Created by Ranorex
 * User: ppatlolla
 * Date: 26/08/2015
 * Time: 10:57 AM
 * 
 * To change this template use Tools | Options | Coding | Edit Standard Headers.
 */
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using WinForms = System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

using Ranorex;
using Ranorex.Core;
using Ranorex.Core.Testing;

namespace CCMWebReports
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of ReadExcelFile.
    /// </summary>
    [TestModule("7FA20A0A-9E9B-4FE2-9DC7-3FAE3AFA5E58", ModuleType.UserCode, 1)]
    public class ReadExcelFile : ITestModule
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new instance.
        /// </summary>
        public ReadExcelFile()
        {
            // Do not delete - a parameterless constructor is required!
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs the playback of actions in this module.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>You should not call this method directly, instead pass the module
        /// instance to the <see cref="TestModuleRunner.Run(ITestModule)"/> method
        /// that will in turn invoke this method.</remarks>
        void ITestModule.Run()
        {
            Mouse.DefaultMoveTime = 300;
            Keyboard.DefaultKeyPressTime = 100;
            Delay.SpeedFactor = 1.0;
        }
    } 


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //public Form1()
       // {
       //     InitializeComponent();
      //  }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp ;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
            Excel.Range range ;

            string str;
            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCnt = 0;

            xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("1010-AgentPerformancebyPeriod-2015081214195339.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

            for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
            {
                for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
                {
                    str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2 ;
                    Report.Info(str);
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                Report.Info("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have too many arguments in your `xlApp.Workbooks.Open` function.

Remove the last 2 parameters after the last 'true' and it should compile successfully:

`xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("1010-AgentPerformancebyPeriod-2015081214195339.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true);`